# Setup React components with Apollo Client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I've been trying to set up my React frontend to access my GraphQL backend with the Apollo client 2. However, I can't make it work and I can't find any "good" resource out there to explain how to do it. I've only found bits of information on how to to do some stuff on the path to set it up. So I've been figuring out all these stuff on my own and I've tried to grasp this whole new way of connecting the frontend with the backend.

In my `package.json` I have these dependencies:

```
"apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.1.4",
"apollo-client": "^2.0.4",
"apollo-link-http": "^1.3.1",
"axios": "^0.16.2",
"graphql": "^0.12.3",
"graphql-tag": "^2.6.0",
```

I chose to break out the `client` to the Apollo client in another file so I could have some organisatino. The client looks like this:

```
import { createHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client';

export const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: new createHttpLink({ uri: 'http://localhost:3010/graphql' }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});
```

And in my `index.js` file, I import the client and all the other necessary stuff:

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { client } from './client'
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import Router from './routes/router'

const App = (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router />            
    </Provider>
  </ApolloProvider>
)

render(App, document.getElementById('root'))
```

With this I should be able to hook up my components to my GraphQL backend and receive data, right?

The only component I've tried to make it work with is this one:

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";
import { graphql } from "react-apollo";
import React from "react";

const HomeLayout = ({ data: { loading, getUsers } }) =>
  (loading ? null : getUsers.map(u => <h1 key={u.id}>{u.name}</h1>))

const allUsersQuery = gql`
  query allUsersQuery {
    getUsers {
      id
      email
    }
  }`;

export default graphql(allUsersQuery)(HomeLayout);
```

The query is correct and I checked my graphiQL which looks like this:
[image]

Now, this might seem like a super easy question, but I have legit no idea how to solve this. I am completely new to this stuff. If someone could guide me or/ and help me solve this issue I would be super grateful! Thanks for reading! Have a good day.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What do they say?

Comment: @cfraser Im getting this: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` in my component.

Comment: @MartinNordström Could you check the data.error property? https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/basics/queries.html#graphql-query-data-error

Comment: @l0rin Hey! I tried it and got `HomeLayout(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.` at my index.js here: `render(App, document.getElementById('root');`

Comment: Yeah I think the issue might be that you should `render(<App />)`

Comment: It's definitely a problem that Apollo Client swallows that error.